# Turn of link click tracking in Tweetdeck

Tags: privacy, twitter, tweetdeck

Lately, I have seen that Tweetdeck/Twitter has started to track clicks on links by replacing links with a t.co based URL link. Is it possible to turn of this so that when you click a link you go directly to the link instead of getting tracked by Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the link shortening is an API feature of the twitter API & cannot be turned off.

Comment: Do you know if the links are unique pr. user pr. link or is it only unique pr. link?